# pdftron html2pdf sample can't work on k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher, html2pdf, pdftron

run from this Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:8
USER root
WORDDIR /root
RUN yum install -y wget java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.i686
RUN wget https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/PDFNetC64.tar.gz
RUN tar xvfz PDFNetC64.tar.gz
RUN cd PDFNetC64/Samples/HTML2PDFTest/JAVA
CMD ["/bin/bash", "RunTest.sh"]
```

The result is perfect, pdfs can be generated.
However, if I deploy the docker image in a k8s (UI: rancher) env, then it stopped working, the screenshot is:

[image: error screenshot]

So could anybody give me some clue? I am doubting there is some special settings in k8s, and because pdftron is calling native so library by JNI, so is there anything I need to pay attention to?
Any idea is appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: I think something is wrong in your Dockerfile - `centos:8` image does not have `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.i686` package. Also you have a type in the Dockerfile content provided: `WORKDIR` instead of `WORDDIR`

Comment: sorry Ilia, I wrote the dockerfile by memory cause I can't login the system then, so there might be some typos. Anyway, we eventually nailed this error by running yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools", I figure there must be some components missing in the system, though we didn't got any time to figure out which component exactly. Thanks anyway!